# Procedure with cursor for counting a number of orders before a given date

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, cursor, procedure

Check if there are any orders before a given date (`Date` column). The procedure has a passing parameter "date" as date and another passing parameter "count". This parameter returns the number of orders before this date.

The simple way of doing it would be:

```
SELECT COUNT([Sales].[dbo].[Order].[Date])
FROM [Sales].[dbo].[Order]
WHERE [Sales].[dbo].[Order].[Date] >= '2019-03-11'
```

But unfortunately I have to use the procedure and the cursor. My attempt is this:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE OrderBeforeDate
    (@date date, 
     @count int OUT)
AS
BEGIN
    SET @count = 0;

    DECLARE cursor1 SCROLL CURSOR FOR
        SELECT [Sales].[dbo].[Order].[Date] 
        FROM [Sales].[dbo].[Order]
        FOR READ ONLY

    OPEN cursor1;

    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor1 INTO @date

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        IF @date <= '2019-03-11'
            SET @count = @count + 1;
    END

    CLOSE cursor1;
    DEALLOCATE cursor1;
END

DECLARE @count int

EXEC OrderBeforeDate @count OUT

PRINT 'Number of Orders after 2019-03-11'': ' + CAST(@count AS VARCHAR(10))
```

But I get the following error message:

> Operand type collision: int is incompatible with date

I don't know what to do. Please give me a helping hand.

Comment: Why use a cursor at all here? SQL is a set based language, and there are very rare occasions you should be using one.

Comment: I totally agree with you, but it's the required default for this project.

Comment: Sound like a very flawed project to require a cursor for something such as this.

Comment: Your stored procedure logic is flawed. You have a date parameter but you are not using it correctly. You can either include that parameter within the cursor definition and just count the rows it returns. Or you can evaluate the date of each row returned by the cursor against the date parameter and increment as needed. The second approach - which is what you implemented - requires another local variable to accept the appropriate column from your cursor. You then compare your parameter with this local variable.

Comment: And one more bad habit - using 3-part names. A procedure will generally exist within a specific database and it will refer to objects (tables) within that same database. Using three part names means that a change to the database name will require changes to the code. Database name changes are common - don't use 3-part names without a good reason.

Comment: @dude this is an absurd requirement. I encourage you to find a better course/teacher, for ask that exercises be set using realistic scenarios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your input! I think it works now with the code like this:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROC OrderBeforeDate(@date date, @count int out)
AS
BEGIN

SET @count = 0;

DECLARE cursor1 scroll cursor for
SELECT [Sales].[dbo].[Order].[Date] 
FROM [Sales].[dbo].[Order]
FOR READ ONLY

OPEN cursor1;
FETCH NEXT FROM cursor1 INTO @date
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
IF @date < '2019-03-11'
    SET @count = @count + 1;
    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor1 INTO @date
END

CLOSE cursor1;
DEALLOCATE cursor1;

END


DECLARE @count int
DECLARE @date date
EXEC OrderBeforeDate @date, @count OUT

PRINT 'Number of Orders before 2019-03-11: ' + CAST(@count AS VARCHAR(10))
```

You're right that this method is way slower than the one I mentioned in the first place. (1 minute versus less than a second)
Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing the expected parameters. In your mock-up I would expect to see

```
DECLARE @count int=0, @Date date='20190311'

EXEC OrderBeforeDate @Date, @count OUT

PRINT 'Number of Orders after 2019-03-11: ' + CAST(@count AS VARCHAR(10))
```

I would also point out (as you presumably already know) this cursor serves no purpose other than to put the brakes on SQL Server performance.

Also your procedure is counting rows *before* your date value, your `print` statement states the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you miss giving the value for date parameter when call OrderBeforeDate procedure. You only pass in 1 argument and SQL server may regard @count value as the value for date paramter.

```
EXEC OrderBeforeDate @count OUT
```

Answer (score 0):

Yor stored procedure expects 2 parameters while you pro ide only one. Date parameter is missing.
Your cursor has infinite loop and yoyr procedure will never end

Using a cursor for this is a verry bad idea, put your count in the sored procedure

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.